# Validate Draggable Customer using the accept function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have question if is this possible regarding to my draggable & droppable module, I  have here classes

1. stackDrop1 (In the Kitchen)
2. stackDrop2 (On the Road)
3. stackDrop3 (Completed)

[image]

If the **Customer George** was on the **On the Road class,** the **class In the  Kitchen** will not allow / Accept to drop the customer George again to that box. It will show alert that the customer already was on the step 2.

**Scenario need to Validate:**
If the **customer George** was already in class stackDrop2 then the class stackDrop1 stop accepting the **customer George**.

My Jquery Codes:

```
    $(".drag-wrapper").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',

});

$("#launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
});

$(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",
    revert: 'invalid',
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        alert('In the kitchen');
    }
});

$(".stackDrop2").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",

    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        alert('On the road');
    }
});

$(".stackDrop3").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",

    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        alert('Completed');
    }
});
```

My Html Codes:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="launchPad">
                <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-25deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white; text-align: center;">
                    <text>Open Orders</text>
                </div>    
                @foreach($customer_orders_details as $transac_details)
                    <div class="drag-wrapper">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <i class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; color:black !important; font-family: 'Open Sans';">OR # {{$transac_details->or_number}}</h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: bold; color:black !important;">Customer: {{$transac_details->customer_name}}</h6><br>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Address: {{$transac_details->order_ship_address}}</h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Contact #: {{$transac_details->customer_number}}</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">Total:${{$transac_details->amount}}</p>

                                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Assign</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-warning" id="gather_customer_order" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="color:white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer_detail_delivery">Details</a>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="dropZone">
                <div class="stack"  style="width:231px;">
                    <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
                        <text>In the Kitchen</text>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="stackDrop1" style="">

                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="dropZone">
                <div class="stack"  style="width:231px;">
                    <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
                        <text>On the Road</text>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="stackDrop2" style="">

                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="dropZone">
                <div class="stack"  style="width:231px;">
                    <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
                        <text>Completed</text>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="stackDrop3" style="">

                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on your description, you want to ensure that customers can only make progress to the right hand side. So George can be dragged from Open Orders to In the Kitchen, from In the Kitchen to On the Road, and from On the Road to Completed, but never backward in that order. Is that correct?

Comment: Your right @Twisty, The validation will be, User will not allow to put back the item in the previous box

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the class for the draggable so that each droppable only accpets specific classes. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag-wrapper").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $("#launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });

  $(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-launch",
    revert: 'invalid',
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("from-launch").addClass("from-kitchen");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      console.log('In the kitchen');
    }
  });

  $(".stackDrop2").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-kitchen",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      console.log('On the road');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div id="launchPad">
        <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-25deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white; text-align: center;">
          <text>Open Orders</text>
        </div>
        <div class="drag-wrapper from-launch">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
              <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">
                <i class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
                <br><br>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; color:black !important; font-family: 'Open Sans';">OR # 1001</h6>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: bold; color:black !important;">Customer: George</h6><br>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Address: 123 Main St, City</h6>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Contact #: (415) 555-1212</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Total:$0.00</p>

                <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Assign</a>
                <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-warning" id="gather_customer_order" data-order-id='OR-1001' data-customer-id='C-1' style="color:white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer_detail_delivery">Details</a>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div id="dropZone">
        <div class="stack" style="width:231px;">
          <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
            <text>In the Kitchen</text>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div class="stackDrop1" style="height: 400px">
            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div id="dropZone">
        <div class="stack" style="width:231px;">
          <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
            <text>On the Road</text>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div class="stackDrop2" style="height: 400px;">

            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div id="dropZone">
        <div class="stack" style="width:231px;">
          <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
            <text>Completed</text>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div class="stackDrop3" style="height: 400px;">

            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As the User moves the items from place to place, classes are added and removed to the item. Each droppable can then accept specific class items. This prevents the user from moving an item into the wrong place.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi @Twisty why i cant put the items in the completed?

Comment: @DevGe the completed did not have a droppable. If it answered your question I hope that you will also Check it as the answer.